# CSS selector inside a specific class

Tags: css, selector

Hi I wonder if I can select a class specifically by its parents.

```
  <div class="naomi"> 
      <div class="pic01"> 
          <div class="pic02">
               <div class="pic05"></div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="teddy"> 
      <div class="pic01">
          <div class="pic05"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

is there a way to select class "pic05" only from class "naomi" without going in order inside like this
          .naomi .pic01 pic02 .pic05

Thank you

Comment: Yes, you can use `.naomi .pic05 { ... }`

Comment: you can also use this https://jsfiddle.net/ebw91j11/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 .naomi .pic05{


}
```

**and**

```
.teddy .pic05{

}
```